# Add new column with initial value in Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input data :

```
col1
-----
123400
123400
123400
123400
123400
```

Expected Output:

```
col1   | col2
------------------
123400 |123401
123400 |123402
123400 |123403
123400 |123404
123400 |123405
```

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zipWithIndex` with the initial value as `123401`

```
val df = Seq(123400, 123400, 123400, 123400, 123400).toDF("col1")

val newDF = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map { case (v, ind) =>
  (v.getInt(0), ind + 123401)
}
.toDF("col1", "col2")

newDF.show(false)
```

Or if you have many other columns and want generic solutions than you can use the same way with the use of schema to construct the dataframe back again

```
val df2 = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index + 123401)
  },
  // Create schema for index column
  StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("col2", LongType, false)))

df2.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------+------+
|col1  |index |
+------+------+
|123400|123401|
|123400|123402|
|123400|123403|
|123400|123404|
|123400|123405|
+------+------+
```

Hope this helps!